# Why I cannot import function from another py file in current directory?

Tags: python, python-import

I cannot import functions from another py file.
How can I import function from another py file in the same directory?
Two py files are in the same directory.
The Python version is 3.7.
OS is Windows 10.
Please help, thank you very much.

db.py

```py
from parser import parser   # No name 'parser' in module 'parser'

def _db():
    '''
        Function: Get sql from GUI, and pass it to paser
    '''
    print('__Start DBMS__')
    # TODO

    print('__End DBMS__')

    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _db()
    parser()
```

parser.py

```py
def parser(_sql=None):
    '''
        Funtion: Get sql string, and parse it and call cressponding functions
    '''
    print('__Start Parsing__')

    # TODO

    print('__End Parsing__')
    pass
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "db.py", line 1, in

```
from parser import parser
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'parser' from 'parser' (unknown location)

Comment: Pick a name that isn't `parser`. [The standard library has dibs on that name.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/parser.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the file name `parser.py` to something else like `parser1.py` and,

```
from parser1 import parser
```

should work as expected.

Because the compiler thinks you are referring to the python `parser` [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/parser.html)

Answer (score 0):

because python have built-in moudle named `parser`, your moudle conflict with it, the solution has two：
1. change your module name.
2. use absolute path, but first, you should add your project directory into PATH, if you use PyCharm, it can help you do it defaultly.

if your project struction like this,

```
...other directory...
  --top_layer
    --second_layer
    --parser.py
```

you can import like this

```
from top_layer.parser import parser
```

excuse my english is poor!